# Set JWT Authorization Header in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwt

I store my JWT token in localStorage and I am trying to use it in a React component via jquery.

This is where the GET request is being made:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/items",
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt'),
      },
      success: function(items) {
        this.setState({items: items});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

This is the backend (flask) for reference:

```
@app.route('/items', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def items():
    items = db.session.query(Item)
    return jsonify([{
        'id': item.id,
        'name': item.name,
        'quantity': item.quantity,
    } for item in items])
```

I think I am writing the jQuery call incorrectly but I can't pin down where exactly, does anyone have suggestions?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to describe the problem.

The javascript is able to retrieve the correct token from `localStorage`. The exact error is `401: Unauthorized`.

I have also tried the following line which gives the same error:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
},
```

Edit: via google chrome console, I saw that the header was actually sent.

Comment: Forgot to include the actual problem, included it now

Comment: instead of JWT you probably want Bearer in your original auth header

Comment: I tried both and unfortunately both lead to a 401. Is there a way to see if the header was actually sent (via js console)?

Comment: Yeah, the network tab in chrome dev tools. You should see all HTTP requests there.